# How to narrow TypeScript discriminated unions based on partially known discriminators?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, discriminated-union, narrowing

I'm working on a React hook for abstracting state for various features that share some function arguments, but where certain feature-specific arguments should be required/disallowed based on which features are enabled. I have the hook function accepting one argument which is an object with a discriminated union type based on boolean feature flag properties, and it returns an object which conditionally includes some properties based on the enabled features:

```
type CustomHookArgs = (
  | ({ isFeatureOneEnabled: true } & FeatureOneArgs)
  | { isFeatureOneEnabled?: false }
) &
  (
    | ({ isFeatureTwoEnabled: true } & FeatureTwoArgs)
    | { isFeatureTwoEnabled?: false }
  ) & {
    someSharedArgsHere: string;
  };

const useCustomHook = (args: CustomHookArgs) => {
  const { isFeatureOneEnabled, isFeatureTwoEnabled } = args;
  // Do some stuff
  return {
    ...args,
    someSharedThings: "here",
    ...(isFeatureOneEnabled && { someFeatureOneThings: "here" }),
    ...(isFeatureTwoEnabled && { someFeatureTwoThings: "here" }),
  };
};
```

If I call `useCustomHook` and start typing the properties of the `CustomHookArgs` object, VS Code IntelliSense will allow/autocomplete the properties of the generic (not yet narrowed) union:

```
{ isFeatureOneEnabled?: boolean; isFeatureTwoEnabled?: boolean; someSharedArgsHere: string }
```

The properties in `FeatureOneArgs` and `FeatureTwoArgs` are considered not part of the `CustomHookArgs` type in this scope and should cause a type error if I include them (which is only working sometimes, but that's a question for another time). If I omit the feature booleans or pass them as `false`, the object returned by `useCustomHook` is correctly inferred to not include the properties `someFeatureOneThings` or `someFeatureTwoThings` (or as I discover now, it infers them as `string | undefined` in the TS playground. That's not what I see in my environment for some reason).

If I call `useCustomHook` with `featureOneEnabled: true`, the args object narrows correctly and TS requires me to pass the required properties from `FeatureOneArgs`, but still not the properties from `FeatureTwoArgs`. Great, so far so good.

```
// No errors, as expected
useCustomHook({
  someSharedArgsHere: "hello"
});
// Error, as expected (someRequiredFeatureOneArg is required)
useCustomHook({
  someSharedArgsHere: "hello"
  isFeatureOneEnabled: true,
});
// No errors, as expected
useCustomHook({
  someSharedArgsHere: "hello",
  isFeatureOneEnabled: true,
  someRequiredFeatureOneArg: "here",
});
```

If I try to take the object returned by the hook and reference properties on it, I would expect to be able to access `someFeatureOneThings` if I passed `isFeatureOneEnabled: true` to the hook. But here's my problem: The return value of the hook is not inferring its type correctly from the narrowed type of `CustomHookArgs` based on values passed into `useCustomHook`. `someFeatureOneThings` still doesn't exist on that object's type (in my env... in the TS playground it's still `string | undefined`). I would expect it to be there with type `string`.

```
const hookReturnObj = useCustomHook({
  someSharedArgsHere: "hello",
  isFeatureOneEnabled: true,
  someRequiredFeatureOneArg: "hey!",
});

// No problem here
console.log(hookReturnObj.someSharedThings);

// Error: Property 'someFeatureOneThings' does not exist on type...
console.log(hookReturnObj.someFeatureOneThings);
```

If I add a conditional around my reference to the feature-specific property, it narrows correctly in that block:

```
if (hookReturnObj.isFeatureOneEnabled) {
  // No more error here
  console.log(hookReturnObj.someFeatureOneThings);
}
```

(Okay, here's another difference in the TS playground -- it doesn't narrow at all there, `someFeatureOneThings` is still `string | undefined`).

But I already told TS `isFeatureOneEnabled` was true when I called `useCustomHook`. Why do I need to narrow it again?

Am I misunderstanding the expected behavior of a discriminated union here? I would expect that leaving the return type of `useCustomHook` to be inferred from its `return` statement would cause the `someFeatureOneThings` property to exist on that type without any conditional if I passed `isFeatureOneEnabled: true`.

As a workaround, is there perhaps a way I can explicitly narrow the type with some custom utility type? Something like this (not real code):

```
type ReturnObjUnion = ReturnType<typeof useCustomHook>;
type ReturnObjWithFeatureOneEnabled = ReturnType<typeof useCustomHook({ isFeatureOneEnabled: true })>;

console.log((hookReturnObj as ReturnObjWithFeatureOneEnabled).someFeatureOneThings);
```

That's not much better than having to add a condition though.

One thing I tried was to add an explicit return type and use `satisfies` (didn't work):

```
type CustomHookReturnObj = {
  someSharedThings: string;
} & (
  | ({ isFeatureOneEnabled: true } & { someFeatureOneThings: string })
  | { isFeatureOneEnabled?: false }
) &
  (
    | ({ isFeatureTwoEnabled: true } & { someFeatureTwoThings: string })
    | { isFeatureTwoEnabled?: false }
  );

const useCustomHook = (args: CustomHookArgs) => {
  const { isFeatureOneEnabled, isFeatureTwoEnabled } = args;
  // Do some stuff
  return {
    ...args,
    someSharedThings: "here",
    (...(isFeatureOneEnabled && { someFeatureOneThings: "here" })),
    (...(isFeatureTwoEnabled && { someFeatureTwoThings: "here" })),
  } satisfies CustomHookReturnObj;
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. [Here's a TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=13&pln=24&pc=5#code/C4TwDgpgBAYhCGwCuAnCB5AdhAgig5gM5QC8UA3gLABQUUhA9gLYQBKEAjkgJZoAmcRKgzY8+AFz1gKbpnwBuGgF8aNUJFgJkaACoB3BmOJkqteszace-Qdoj7DBSYWmyFy1dXXQAwkhfMABIMDADWRqRQABQ0dAA+0eRQ3IS2wlgQAKKY8ABGADYQfJLSSNBKUABkmkJoGUYAlLFQCUkpaXXY2XmFfAD8kgBm8PmE5TQNVc0xZvGJyalawg7dBUUlKGVQFdUd9gaNzXNti7X7DKu9A1DDo+Nmk9WmdHSMLADKABbw-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-CN0i6ETijEspmXjdTrC0h16icNsM0DHchSHa9ZLHCdFNvRdl2ctcLA3ZMiHSqAvgYJB8k5IypH3fBmVyJBqW4YBYOIFxuA7Bq3EPJBj1Pc9OQxfB4Fkb8FT-ADgKI4hiLAuE3yyuTkipBA+EozxuBwqIVyc5V7SE8LLK2xU6AO4qWFKrdyqkkUoJg+CoBybK9CgP1oAgdq-WZPQDUhT4SL4XbBnNTA2um-8ICA3gYRYSGbjHLUoDQScYSopQgA) where I've been trying to reproduce this, although I'm seeing different results there than in my project (as noted above).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Do I understand correctly that you haven't been able to come up with a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted into another IDE?  If so I'm not sure how we can proceed, or at least not in a way where we can test potential solutions.

Comment: If you want the type of a function's output to depend on its input, you either need to make the function *generic*, or *overload* the function.  And the kind of logic you're doing is not going to be something the compiler can track, so it will not be able to accurately verify the implementation of the function.  If you want to make the function generic you can type it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0Vnqw), but you're taking responsibility for type safety into your own hands here.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write this up as an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, your example definitely helps me move in the right direction. The code in my question was my attempt at creating a minimal reproducible example, the real code in my project is already quite overloaded with generics. I hadn't considered just making the feature flags themselves additional generic type parameters. That might be the solution.

Comment: As far as an actual minimal reproducible example of the behavior I was seeing in my project, I'll see if I can find time to come back to it and update the question. But it seems you may have already solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your `useCustomHook()` function is implemented as a single block of code that depends on an `args` parameter of the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `CustomHookArgs`.  But the compiler can only analyze that block of code *once*.  It doesn't "distribute" its analysis across the union members of `CustomHookArgs`.  So it loses all track of various *correlations*, and the returned union is wider than you want it to be, including terms that will not actually be possible.  You get a kind of indiscriminate mixture of cases.  There's no way to even ask for the compiler to analyze a single block this way (see [microsoft/TypeScript#25051](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051) for a declined feature request).  If you want the compiler to properly account for the different possibilities, you need to actually write one a block of code for each case, like this:

```
const useCustomHook = (args: CustomHookArgs) => {
  const { isFeatureOneEnabled, isFeatureTwoEnabled } = args;
  if (isFeatureOneEnabled && isFeatureTwoEnabled) {
    return {
      ...args,
      someSharedThings: "here",
      someFeatureOneThings: "here",
      someFeatureTwoThings: "here",
    }
  }
  if (isFeatureOneEnabled && !isFeatureTwoEnabled) {
    return {
      ...args,
      someSharedThings: "here",
      someFeatureOneThings: "here",
    }
  }

  if (!isFeatureOneEnabled && isFeatureTwoEnabled) {
    return {
      ...args,
      someSharedThings: "here",
      someFeatureTwoThings: "here"
    }
  }

  return {
    ...args,
    someSharedThings: "here",
  }
}
```

That's quite redundant, but at least the output doesn't contain any impossible union members.  Conversely, if you want to write a single `return` statement, you'll probably need to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or the like to convince the compiler that the value conforms to your desired output type.

---

Furthermore, you are expecting the return type of `useCustomHook()` to depend on how you call it.  But that doesn't happen automatically with union inputs.  The only ways to get a function to output different *types* depending on the input types is to either [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) it make it [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

And again, the compiler is unlikely to be able to follow the logic of your implementation either way.  Overloads will generally allow unsafe implementations without complaint, and generics will generally be prematurely widened to constraints and you'll get errors for safe implementations.  Either way you will probably have to take some of the type safety responsibility upon yourself, since either the compiler will allow too much (so you need to be careful) or too little (so you need to use a type assertion, which also requires care).

---

It's up to you which way you'd like to proceed.  One possibility is to make the function generic, come up with a type relationship between input and output types, and just assert that your implementation behaves that way.  Maybe like this:

```
type CustomHookArgs<F1 extends boolean, F2 extends boolean> =
  { isFeatureOneEnabled?: F1, isFeatureTwoEnabled?: F2, someSharedArgsHere: string } &
  { true: { someRequiredFeatureOneArg: string }, false: {} }[`${F1}`] &
  { true: { someRequiredFeatureTwoArg: string }, false: {} }[`${F2}`];

type CustomHookReturn<F1 extends boolean, F2 extends boolean> =
  { someSharedThings: string } &
  {
    true: { isFeatureOneEnabled: true, someFeatureOneThings: string },
    false: { isFeatureOneEnabled?: false }
  }[`${F1}`] &
  {
    true: { isFeatureTwoEnabled: true, someFeatureTwoThings: string },
    false: { isFeatureTwoEnabled?: false }
  }[`${F2}`];


const useCustomHook = <F1 extends boolean = false, F2 extends boolean = false>(
  args: CustomHookArgs<F1, F2>) => {
  const { isFeatureOneEnabled, isFeatureTwoEnabled } = args;
  return {
    ...args,
    someSharedThings: "here",
    ...(isFeatureOneEnabled && { someFeatureOneThings: "here" }),
    ...(isFeatureTwoEnabled && { someFeatureTwoThings: "here" }),
  } as CustomHookReturn<boolean, boolean> as CustomHookReturn<F1, F2>;
};
```

Essentially the function is generic in the `boolean` types of the `isFeatureOneEnabled` and `isFeatureTwoEnabled` properties, `F1`, and `F2` respectively.  If you leave out the properties (and the compiler fails to infer the generic from it) then they [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `false`.  The input is of type `CustomHookArgs<F1, F2>` and the output is of type `CustomHookReturn<F1, F2>`.  Both the input and output essentially switch on `F1` and `F2` by using [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that use the [stringified template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) of `F1` and `F2` as the index.  This is a bit of a hack to avoid [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).  If you want you could replace `` {true: X, false: Y}[`${F}`] `` with `F extends true ? X : Y`.

Anyway let's just make sure it works as desired from the call side:

```
const obj1 = useCustomHook({
  someSharedArgsHere: "hello"
}); // okay
// const obj1: CHR<false, false>
obj1.someFeatureOneThings; // error
// Property 'someFeatureOneThings' does not exist on type 'CustomHookReturn<false, false>'

const obj2 = useCustomHook({
  someSharedArgsHere: "hello",
  isFeatureOneEnabled: true
}); // error!
// Property 'someRequiredFeatureOneArg' is missing.

const obj3 = useCustomHook({
  someSharedArgsHere: "hello",
  isFeatureOneEnabled: true,
  someRequiredFeatureOneArg: "here"
}); // okay
// const obj3: CHR<true, false>
obj3.someFeatureOneThings; // string
```

Looks good.  Again, you might want to use a different approach, but you'll be subject to the same general issues as outlined above.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBNArvA1kg3gWACgkkAXATxmQGE0oSB7MACXvswEEAnAcyiQF5CxYgAocSAJZQAYhBAk0nCAHlgEAKKgARgBsIAEwBcpTmggAaJFEYQAShACOaCUv2z5ilWq7djdThLA3EgAvkgAPriSMnIKSqoa2nr6APzGAGYgOlDIIQCUSABkQsJi0e5xEAAqAO70miC6BsYkphZWNvZOLgYVnrX0Pn6tgcFhkeJSfUoDDU2pGVk5oQXFRMLi1pAAygAWIK4+UEwQSsMBQQDcoZeEJfD0wHRItBA0dIwsbAJIIge8xneDGYrA4PCgBX4AD5cCViA8niQolNYp4EnNkpYUR4ZnUMQZQj9-lBbutiBJ0r9sZV0UkCYVCuVUbj6nT9AV8GThEo4sBYVzhEgAHQi4nmOGCjo7fauKq7UZQYwAIl2pwgSvFAuEWwg0y81XlQUVSBVao1EsFOr1AzlCuVqqU5q1IQlLq5FKpMRx+vx+iKjIAhNT+ni2RyLUgeYo+ZzJcIRUKxRHiDq9gcDLajfazZq4ymbHqEpmASaHerc5K3YK3RKPSIg16aWpff6md7ZmH+XGo5wY8nhaLwRW46mZRnDSXTY7h5KrczqnVi8ap+qI1XhDWuT2+1qE0mtaP0-ol9np66SpvN4RyJQkEDPqCjgAeaQARiQEAAHiQIMB9HwtFYPQQGASxpAAJg-b9f3-JBAPoYDgBhQR1kmRs0WbNk0iQN8sXQllfWwiDLEPQ5wROM4rBGIJCTWYhxFaMxjE2TpHGcVxC28HhzlGUJLEybIIGYsIQgAbQAAwAEhwN8QnEgBdIoSgYtpmKlOw2J6Nx5wGIYqIuMZ+KWITcBEiTpIguT5NJa8KGoWhgS+TB7F5F93y-H8-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-ThY84AME6QZP6FT9Os9Y7oOJJnx86kJAwCkKBRiFTvu7VgBmH4tY+CWh-zaUj1HyiTbNp1yS6mf5hzwsHrfe7FehH24szVcBArZIBdmwR2G9b6qzvl7H2yVW45EDgQD2d9Q65XDmoJcS9YpBE7kAA)